# How to proper set up a destructor in C++ with Xcode?

Tags: c++, class, destructor

there is something that has been bugging me for a while.
I cannot create a **destructor** using Xcode (with other IDEs like VS2021 that is no issue).

I get the error:

```
1. Constructor cannot be redeclared
2. Missing return type for function '˜Pointer'; did you mean the constructor name 'Pointer'?
```

If I try to declare outside of the class and uncomment the lines in *.cpp and *.hpp the errors get even crazier.

My **Pointers.hpp** is the following:

```cpp
#ifndef Pointers_hpp
#define Pointers_hpp
#include <iostream>

class Pointer{

public:
    Pointer(void);
    ˜Pointer(void){};
    //˜Pointer(void);

};
#endif /* Pointers_hpp */
```

and my **Pointers.cpp** is this one:

```cpp
#include "Pointers.hpp"

Pointer::Pointer(void){};
//Pointer::˜Pointer(void){};
```

After several research in the internet, I could not find a solution to that, could any one give me a light on this?

Many thanks in advance,
Raphael

Comment: `˜` doesn't seem to be a `~`

Comment: You already declared your destructor body in the header file, just omit the body (`{}`) there.

Comment: Thank you but the error still keeps the same "Constructor cannot be redeclared" with or without the {}

Comment: You got it right user4581301, using ~ worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved thanks to user4581301:**

For those having the same problem I did.
The issue here was the similarity between `˜` and `~`

The correct one should be `~`

If you are using **MacBook Pro** the short-key is `Option-N`.